# Getting results of Javascript onclick using Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

Hi I am new to Selenium and not sure if I'm using it in the right way at all.

What I am trying to do is get some data from a web page. This data is put into a blank div as the result of a javascript function expand_all(). I have an "a" link which calls the javascript function on the page like so:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="expand_all()" class="expand-all" id="btn_expand">Show stuff</a>
```

What i want to do now is use Selenium to click that button, and then get the data which is added into the div. This is what I have so far (builds on selenium's "getting started" code):

```
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());

driver.findElement(By.className("expand-all")).click();

System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());

(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                int i;

                public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                    i = d.findElements(By.tagName("table")).size();
                    System.out.println(i);
                    return (i == 8);
                }
            });
```

The wait should break when the number of visible tables in the page is 8. (The div is populated with tables), however the number never changes. And the page source is exactly the same before and after the click function is called...

So my question is -how have I gone wrong? Can selenium do what I want it to do?

Comment: Have you verified - e.g. using `console.log` or `alert('here')` - that `expand_all()` actually gets called by your click? If it's not actually called, that would explain the rest.

Comment: Well the trouble is it's not my site. But when I click the button it works in the browser, is there a difference between that and the selenium click()?

Comment: Shouldn't be, no. However, are you waiting for the page to fully load before calling `click()`? Your code is a lot quicker at clicking than you and the JS may not be loaded.

Comment: Ah, is there a way to check? I've definitely clicked the button, but I hadn't thought of the Javascript not existing... wouldn't Selenium throw an error?

Comment: There are lots of examples of how to do waits out there, e.g. http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/webdriver-wait-examples. You could either have a hardcoded wait (fine for one-off testing) or simply wait until a particular element on your page becomes usable, at which point it's probably safe to assume your JS is likewise usable.

Comment: Yup I've waited for 20 seconds both before and after the clicks but still no change occurs.

Comment: Should the selenium driver automatically just add this new content to its DOM? There's definitely nothing I have to call like driver.refreshDOM() or something...?

Comment: I forgot to ask whether your `apply()` method was logging anything: (a) at all, (b) if the table count was increasing or not. Also, if I had any doubt about the JS method getting called I'd probably take a copy of the site and hack the method to produce logging of its own. BTW, no, you definitely don't need to tell Selenium about the DOM changing.